# How to display data in paging table with POST actions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am trying to find the best method for displaying data in a paging table that uses POST to retrieve appropriate data. The problem is when the POST value `Inactive` executes and then I navigate to the second page of the data displays the `Active` data instead. I believe this is cause by the default data being `Active` and the code is not tracking the previous search. I can't seem to find the correct method to solve this. Do I have to use some AJAX or jQuery to track the previous POST value?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. There is no any *previous* POST values. You have to pass the post values *EACH TIME, manually*.

Comment: @zerkms Okay, I just thought there could be a better method. I will give this a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I have finally found a similar problem that has helped. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223341/codeigniter-pagination-with-selected-records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$config['suffix'] = '?'.http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");`

I changed my `POST` to `GET` then I add the line above and I worked perfectly.

Reference: [codeigniter pagination url with get parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384644/codeigniter-pagination-url-with-get-parameters)

Thanks